# How to fetch an API data and use it as a Highchart Data object using React

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

How we Fetch in Functional componenets the API data and pass it as Highcharts data ?

Comment: Please clarify the specific problem. At the very least, that's two _separate_ tasks you could research individually.

Comment: Kindly give some demo of Highcharts where I can fetch data and use it as a data object
I hope you all understand

Comment: There are many such examples in the documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Can you kindly help me  by giving me some link of those

Comment: I actually new in this Highcharts era , I can load csv and make graph and chart , but not done the part of fetching data from API

Comment: Then research how to fetch data in React. There are thousands of resources about that already.